# Is it ok to destroy a std::promise before future.get() is called?

Tags: c++, concurrency, promise, future

I was wondering if it is ok to call promise.get_future(), move that future somewhere else (e.g. into a vector) and possibly let the promise die before even the future.get() is called. In the following example, the call `gateway->refreshWithCallback` executes the lambda in a thread so that the shared pointer may set the promise free even if in the second loop the future.get() was not called yet, which seems to work but I am angsty!

```
std::vector<std::future<bool>> futures;
for(GuiGateway *gateway : gateways){
    std::shared_ptr<std::promise<bool>> shared_promise_ptr(new std::promise<bool>());
    futures.push_back(shared_promise_ptr.get()->get_future());
    gateway->refreshWithCallback([shared_promise_ptr](bool success){
        shared_promise_ptr.get()->set_value(success);
    });
}

qDebug() << "waiting for futures";

for(std::future<bool> &future : futures){
    if(future.get() == false){
        qDebug() << "error retrieving all gateway data, aborting auto config";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there exists [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which may be a bit more efficient at creating new objects that will be stored in a `std::shared_ptr` (allocates enough memory for the object and the control block in one shot) and covers an edge case regarding exception safety. It also saves on repetition, you can write `auto shared_promise_ptr = std::make_shared<std::promise<bool>>();`.

Comment: I would up-vote this question if it was a little more succinct. The example is unnecessarily specific (and thus verbose), You could make it simpler and more general.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you provide a value to the `std::promise` before destroying it, the associated `std::future` will be able to retrieve it just fine. It does not depend on `std::promise` still existing. If you failed to provide a value to `std::promise` before destroying it, trying to get a result from the `std::future` will throw [`std::future_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_error) but it is also well defined.

Comment: I love this answer. It wipes away a hole in my understanding. To be more concrete: in a (potential) asynchronous function I can use a local promise to bail out in a synchronous error path. Not caring (yet) about the `promise` a asynchronous-call will make later on.

Comment: If providing a value is fine, is setting an exception fine as well? I’d assume yes, because all it comes to is if the shared state exists after `~std::promise` runs.

Comment: @Bolpat Providing an exception instead of a value follows the same reasoning and will work following the same rules.