# Lifetime of promise and set_value_at_thread_exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise

Suppose we have the following code:

```
std::promise<int> promise;
auto future = promise.get_future();

const auto task = [](auto promise) {
    try {            
        promise.set_value_at_thread_exit(int_generator_that_can_throw());
    } catch (...) {
        promise.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
    }
};
    
std::thread thread(task, std::move(promise));
// use future
thread.join();
```

I wonder if this code is correct and safe, and if no, why.

It appears to work fine when compiled with GCC, but crashes (no message is printed) when compiled with MSVC (2017). My guess is that a crash happens because `promise` local variable inside `task` goes out of scope and is destroyed too early. If I remove `_at_thread_exit` suffixes, this code works as expected (or appears to work). It also works correctly when the promise is captured:

```
const auto task = [p = std::move(promise)]() mutable {
    /*...*/
};
```

[Complete compilable example](https://godbolt.org/z/398cv5T6W)

Comment: Looks like a lifetime issue to me.  `promise` gets moved into the `operator()` of the closure object, and once that function call ends, it gets destroyed, leaving `future` pointer to shared state that no longer exists.

Comment: I think you are right. Promise looks like it is destructed too early. I am kind of wondering if it will be safe to use the future you got at the beginning after moving the promise. Future has a tight link with the *this of the promise (if I understand the docs good enough). 
If I replace the promise with a shared_ptr to promise there is no crash anymore.. a further indication that this is a life cycle isseu.

Comment: @NathanOliver But destroying a promise after a value is set [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48408421) destroy the shared state and invalidate a future.

Comment: @Evg the problem is with the fact that (probably) `promise` object must still exist when thread local storage is destroyed  when  `_at_thread_exit` function is used. This means promise should not be in the scope of the thread

Comment: BTW, this question can be boiled down to this - should `_at_thread_exit` functions work correctly when `std::promise` object no longer exists. I suppose answer is no

Comment: @bartop Another question is when `_at_thread_exit` gets called in relation to the existence of the lambda object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does your code generate problems? Let's start with ansewer to 'when `_at_thread_exit` writes to shared state of `std::future` and `std::promise`?'. [It happens after destruction of all thread local variables.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/futures.promise#24) Your lambda is called within the thread and after its scope is left, the promise is already destroyed. But what happens when thread calling your lambda has some thread-local variables? Well, the writing will occur after destruction of the `std::promise` object. Actually, the rest is really undefined in standard. It seems that passing data to shared state could be done after destruction of `std::promise` but information is not really there.

Simplest solution is of course this:

```
std::promise<int> promise;
auto future = promise.get_future();

const auto task = [](std::promise<int>& promise) {
    try {            
        promise.set_value_at_thread_exit(int_generator_that_can_throw());
    } catch (...) {
        promise.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
    }
};
    
std::thread thread(task, std::ref(promise));
// use future
thread.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently endeavor to understand the mechanism of future-promise and encounter the same problem. I read the source code and C++ standard and finally figure out what happens. **The problem doesn't lie in "promise is destructed so garbage memory is accessed", but in its inconsistency.**

## TL;DR

If `xx_at_thread_exit` is called, you shouldn't make `std::promise` destruct before the thread exits (i.e. end of passed functor), because it will try to set both value and exception. It seems that MS-STL does what is regulated in the standard while libc++/libstdc++ doesn't.

## Future-Promise model

In C++, a promise represents a worker who "promises to give some result", while a future represents a collector who "wants the future result". They share a shared state, where the result (value or exception) is stored. Also, such a connection is a nonce channel, meaning that each end can only set/get the result once, unless you turn a `std::future` into a `std::shared_future` to make it able to get multiple times.

There are three cases for the shared state:

- Neither set result, nor ready; `std::promise` may call `set_value`, `set_exception`, `set_value_at_thread_exit` and `set_exception_at_thread_exit` once.
- Set result, but not ready; This is because `std::promise` calls `xx_at_thread_exit`, so it'll be ready when the functor passed to the thread ends (and after all local variables are destructed).
- Set result, and ready; This is because `set_value` or `set_exception`, or `xx_at_thread_exit` when the functor completely ends.

Particularly, when the promise is destructed before ready, the shared state will be *abandoned* in dtor, meaning that an exception `std::future_error` (broken promise) will be set.

A shared state is just like a `std::shared_ptr` held by both `std::future` and `std::promise`; whoever destructs will make reference count -1, and when the reference count goes to 0, the shared state is deleted.

## Lifetime concern

So now, we know that after calling `xx_at_thread_exit`, the result is stored. Making it `ready` happens totally in the shared state (the usual implementation will store a condition variable and register such an event on it), which will not be interfered with the destruction of `std::promise`. That's why I say the problem doesn't lie in "promise is destructed so garbage memory is accessed".

Then why MS-STL will terminate the program? That's because [C++ standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/futures.state#7) regulates that *abandon* doesn't check whether it has set the result, but checks whether it's ready. But `set_value_at_thread_exit` doesn't make it ready yet, so the exception `std::future_error` (**broken_promise**) will be set.

However, a shared state should have either a value or an exception! MS-STL basically just calls `set_exception`, so the stored value makes it throw `std::future_error` (**promise_already_satisfied**). But it's in a `noexcept` dtor! So `std::terminate` is called and thus the program is aborted.

For libc++/libstdc++, `std::promise` will cut off the connection with the stored result once it's set. Thus, the exception won't be set in dtor and the program runs normally. This slightly violates the standard, since it should have both the value and the exception; but then it will violate the future-promise model. So, unless the standard is revised, the implementation of MS-STL is more reasonable for me to both fulfill the standard and the abstract model.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>();
    auto future = promise->get_future();

    const auto task = [](const std::shared_ptr<std::promise<int>>& p) 
    {
        try 
        {
            p->set_value_at_thread_exit(42);
        }
        catch (...) 
        {
            p->set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
        }
    };

    std::thread thread(task, promise);
    // use future
    thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To me `std::shared_ptr` is an overkill because `std::promise`+`std::future` already have some shared state. We could just capture `promise` by reference.

Comment: Yes for this bit of code that would do to. By the way what you are doing looks a bit like : std::packaged_task.

Comment: Yes, `std::packaged_task` is an option. But I'm more interested in understanding why the code fails (to me this is not clear) rather than in how to make it work.

Comment: I can understand that. Debugging it now myself. Funny thing is if I move the promise on the mainthread its fine. If the promise is destructed it looks like it can't lock a mutex ... like that mutex is closely coupled to the thread that created the promise in the first place.  Bit weird, can't really figure it out